# Bootstrap a Web App with Groovy config in Spring

Tags: spring, web-applications, groovy, config

Is there a way to bootstrap a Web application using Groovy Config just like JavaConfigWebApplicationContext for java config.And I know Grails does that under the hood but I don't use grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [spring-boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) which has a native support for groovy and gradle

Then, it's simple to deploy your application with a jar launcher embedding Tomcat or Jetty; you can use a gradle task to create a war too.

Here is an example of a boot application configuration using groovy:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class GreetingApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingApplication, args)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Spring boot seems to be interesting